# Getting dual solutions in pyscipopt

Tags: python, optimization, scip

If we need dual solutions of a LP solve, is it necessary to switch off presolve and disable propagation? Is there some other (more relaxed) setting which achieves the same goal?

Also, can we get the entire dual solution vector instead of calling `getDualsolLinear` for every constraint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you need to turn them off, since SCIP does not offer dual postsolving (since it is itself not an LP solver). Therefore, you will not be able to retrieve dual solutions of constraints that get removed/changed/etc during presolving or propagation.
If you really need presolving, I suggest to just directly use an LP solver (e.g. [SoPlex](https://soplex.zib.de/) or [HiGHS](https://www.highs.dev/)) although I'm not sure about the availability of a Python interface in those cases.

There is no method that returns the entire solutions vector (though it would of course be easy to just implement a small wrapper yourself that calls `getDualSolLinear` on every constraint.